# How to Implement zooming effect in winapi?

Tags: windows, winapi, graphics, zooming

I want my application to zoom in and zoom out on `ctrl+wheel` message, Like it does in chrome/mozila. How can I implement this zoom out and zoom in effect? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean the [`WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: Yes WM_MOUSEWHEEL with wparam MK_CONTROL, I want little help on logic for implementing this effect.

Comment: So great, you know how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Perhaps render to an offscreen device context, and use StretchBlt.

Answer (score 2):

1. Listen for the mouse event(s) you want to trigger your zoom.
2. When these occur, check if the relevant modifier key is pressed.
3. Perform your zoom action if appropriate.

You'll need to record at least:

- The current zoom level.
- A min / max zoom level.
- A "zoom interval" the amount / percentage by which your view zooms in / out on each event.

Then you'll have to update your rendering to support zooming, in whatever way makes sense for your application. It could be:

- Altering the font size.
- Scaling control sizes.
- Scaling images.
- All of the above

Hopefully this gives you an idea of how to approach the problem.